# Paint Protection

Tags: paint-clearcoat

When you get paint Protection put on new Honda car do you have to go back to get it replied every year for the warranty? And if so do you have to pay for them to put new  coat on every year?

Ziebart cost $1000. for Ziebart and Diamond Gloss Finish  so post to last 10 Years but they want you to bring it back for new coat every year $200.00.

Just wondering what deal is better.

Comment: Paint protection systems are high profit add-ons sold by the individual dealer. You will have to find which specific product your dealer is using. Then check the fine print for their requirements.